# Swift: Image auto constraints with view background

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am starting out with Swift and tried to search for an answer but couldn't come across one. I have a `UIViewController` and within it, I am working the layout of components (labels, buttons, images, etc.).

For the sake of getting a nice look, I used `UIView` and changed its color to grey shade. Inside it I have an image of the logo and I am trying to apply auto constraints within it but I can't seem to get it right as for some reason it stretches the image out of the view.

I've added images for before the auto constrain and after auto constraint for your reference.

Before auto constraints:

[image: Before constraints]

After auto constraints:

[image: After constraints]

There are no constraints set in the code. Only in the Interface Builder.

Comment: Did you set constraints to that grey View ? First you have to set constraints for view and then to imageView

Comment: It seems you didn't set constraints of the parent view of imageView.

Comment: remove the constraints set for logo and 1) set constraints for imageview first .  2) set constrints for logo

Comment: @shraddha11 I tried that but for some reason it simply doesn't cover all the way to the top. So I can still see some whitespace.

Comment: Select top constraint of your view and change it's item to Safe area instead of SuperView.Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give Top, leading, trailing, aspect ratio constraints and set image content mode to Aspect fit. 
Attaching screenshot for your reference[image]

Comment: Thanks Suresh. I believe all other answers are leading to the same outcome, but following yours it helped me solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome @khalid

Answer (score 0):

When working with auto layout, you have to provide enough constraints for the views to have an unambiguous position and size. In your case, you are creating constraints in the image view that reference it’s superview (the gray view). The problem is that the gray view itself does not have specific constraints, so, instead of resizing the image view, the gray view is being resized. 
From your first screenshot, it seems like the needed constraints for the gray view would be something like:

```
leading == superview.leading
trailing == superview.trailing
top == superview.top
```

Keep in mind that the same visual can be created with different constraints, like

```
centerX == superview.centerX
width == superview.width
top == superview.top
```

so, there isn’t only one answer.

Also, later you will need to provide constraints for the other views, like your UIButtons.

Answer (score 0):

[image: See this image to change top constraint]

Select top constraint -> Double click on top constraint and open details -> Change it's second item to Safe area instead of SuperView.

Comment: What has to be selected before applying the above?